# Ayuda con ADO.NET data model

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

Saludos utilizo entity framework y recientemente tengo inconvenientes en el proceso de seleccion de tablas con el asistente, ya reinstale el componente de entity framework y continua igual. el problema es que **al llegar a esta ventana:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**en vez de salirme como es la forma habitual, me sale lo siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el proceso se realiza de forma normal pero en ocasiones solo ocupo seleccionar algunas tablas y debido a que no me presenta nada tengo que seleccionarlas todas o no funciona, como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: la base de datos esta local en la pc, o te conectas a un server remoto ? que seria el "no funciona"? obtienes algun otor mensaje de error

Comment: la base de datos es local y cuando digo no funciona es que como veras en la primera imagen puedes seleccionar las tablas que desees 1 por 1, es decir podria facilmente elegir cliente y producto y todo funcionaria sin problemas, ahora como no me carga ninguna de las tablas sino le doy click al cuadro de tablas el cual selecciona todas las tablas el proceso de conexion es inservible

Comment: la base de datos en ambas imagenes es la misma pero en la segunda que es la pc que tiene problemas con el proceso de seleccion no se visualizan ningunas de las tablas y no entiendo porque si al final de cuentas si lo realizo de forma normal termina funcionando pero agregandome todas las tablas de la base de datos. hay bases de datos que tienen 30 tablas y solo ocupo 5 o menos y tengo que cargarlas todas